# Is there an R function that reads text files with \n as a (column) delimiter?

Tags: r, data.table, readr

## The Problem

I'm trying to come up with a neat/fast way to read files delimited by newline (`\n`) characters into more than one column.

Essentially in a given input file, multiple rows in the input file should become a single row in the output, however most file reading functions sensibly interpret the newline character as signifying a new row, and so they end up as a data frame with a single column. Here's an example:

The input files look like this:

```
Header Info
2021-01-01
text
...
@
2021-01-02
text
...
@
...
```

Where the `...` represents potentially multiple rows in the input file, and the `@` signifies what should really be the end of a row in the output data frame. So upon reading this file, it should become a data frame like this (ignoring the header):

| X1 | X2 | ... | Xn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | text | ... | ... |
| 2021-01-02 | text | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

## My attempt

I've tried `base`, `data.table`, `readr` and `vroom`, and they all have one of two outputs, either a data frame with a single column, or a vector. I want to avoid a for loop, and so my current solution is using `base::readLines()`, to read it as a character vector, then manually adding some "proper" column separators (e.g. `;`), and then joining and splitting again.

```r
# Save the example data to use as input
writeLines(c("Header Info", "2021-01-01", "text", "@", "2021-01-02", "text", "@"), "input.txt")

input <- readLines("input.txt")
input <- paste(input[2:length(input)], collapse = ";") # Skip the header
input <- gsub(";@;*", replacement = "\n", x = input)
input <- strsplit(unlist(strsplit(input, "\n")), ";")
input <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, input)

# Clean up the example input
unlink("input.txt")
```

My code above works and gives the desired result, but surely there's a better way??
**Edit:** This is internal in a function, so part (perhaps the larger part) of the intention of any simplification is to improve the speed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are looking for a fast way to do it, I would suggest something like `grep` or `sed` on a unix OS to replace all \n with some delimitter and then @ with \n. Then read in the data.
Otherwise the R package stringi is quite fast for string manipulation. That is to say, I am not aware of any package that allows you to split by newline.

Comment: Also to replace your last steps, most data read functions take vectors as input, i.e., `fread("hello,world\n1,2")` works as does `readr::read_csv("hello,world\n1,2")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** Read in the data, locate the @ signs giving logical variable at and then create a grouping variable g which has distinct values for each desired line. Finally use tapply with paste to rework it into lines that can be read using read.table and read it.  (If there are commas in the data then use some other separating character.)

```
L <- readLines("input.txt")[-1]
at <- grepl("@", L)
g <- cumsum(at)
read.table(text = tapply(L[!at], g[!at], paste, collapse = ","), 
  sep = ",", col.names = cnames)
```

giving this data frame:

```
          V1   V2
1 2021-01-01 text
2 2021-01-02 text
```

**2)** Another approach is to rework the data into dcf form by removing the @ sign and prefacing other lines with their column name and a colon.  Then use read.dcf.  cnames is a character vector of column names that you want to use.

```
cnames <- c("Date", "Text")

L <- readLines("input.txt")[-1]
LL <- sub("@", "", paste0(c(paste0(cnames, ": "), ""), L))
DF <- as.data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(LL)))
DF[] <- lapply(DF, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
DF
```

giving this data frame:

```
        Date Text
1 2021-01-01 text
2 2021-01-02 text
```

**3)** This approach simply reshapes the data into a matrix and then converts it to a data frame.  Note that (1) converts numeric columns to numeric whereas this one just leaves them as character.

```
L <- readLines("input.txt")[-1]
k <- grep("@", L)[1]
as.data.frame(matrix(L, ncol = k, byrow = TRUE))[, -k]
##           V1   V2
## 1 2021-01-01 text
## 2 2021-01-02 text
```

### Benchmark

The question did not mention speed as a consideration but in a comment it was later mentioned.  Based on the data  in the benchmark below (1) runs over twice as fast as the code in the question and (3) runs nearly 25x faster.

```
library(microbenchmark)

writeLines(c("Header Info", 
   rep(c("2021-01-01", "text", "@", "2021-01-02", "text", "@"), 10000)), 
   "input.txt")

library(microbenchmark)
writeLines(c("Header Info", rep(c("2021-01-01", "text", "@", "2021-01-02", "text", "@"), 10000)), "input.txt")

microbenchmark(times = 10,
ques = {
  input <- readLines("input.txt")
  input <- paste(input[2:length(input)], collapse = ";") # Skip the header
  input <- gsub(";@;*", replacement = "\n", x = input)
  input <- strsplit(unlist(strsplit(input, "\n")), ";")
  input <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, input)
},
ans1 = {
  L <- readLines("input.txt")[-1]
  at <- grepl("@", L)
  g <- cumsum(at)
  read.table(text = tapply(L[!at], g[!at], paste, collapse = ","), sep = ",")
},
ans3 = {
  L <- readLines("input.txt")[-1]
  k <- grep("@", L)[1]
  as.data.frame(matrix(L, ncol = k, byrow = TRUE))[, -k]
})
## Unit: milliseconds
##  expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq     max neval cld
##  ques 1146.62 1179.65 1188.74 1194.78 1200.11 1219.01    10   c
##  ans1  518.95  522.75  548.33  532.59  561.55  647.14    10  b 
##  ans3   50.47   51.19   51.68   51.69   52.25   52.52    10 a
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Option one worked, but wasn't any faster than my solution, and option 2 didn't work, because the column names are potentially unknown upfront (sorry, probably should have been in the original post). I appreciate your effort though!

Comment: The qeustion did not say anything about speed. The focus was on simplifying the loop.

Comment: Well the first line mentions neat/fast, but fair point, it could have been more explicit. If you have any other suggestions with speed in mind, I'd be very happy to hear them.

Comment: Have added a third approach and a benchmark.  The third approach runs nearly 25x faster than the code in the question using the data in the benchmark.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much! I've accepted your answer though, because of your third solution, which is both elegant and much faster than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can get round some of the string manipulation with something along the lines of:

```
input <- readLines("input.txt")[-1] #Read in and remove header
ncol <- which(input=="@")[1]-1  #Number of columns of data
data.frame(matrix(input[input != "@"], ncol = ncol, byrow=TRUE)) #Convert to dataframe 
#          X1   X2
#1 2021-01-01 text
#2 2021-01-02 text
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I had been hovering around, and about 4-6 times faster. I'll add some benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, you might consider going the full mile and use a proper grammar to parse it. I don't know how big or complex the situation really is, but using *pegr* it might look something like this:

```r
input <-
"Header Info
2021-01-01
text
multiple lines
of
text
@
2021-01-02
text
more
lines of text
@
"

library(pegr)
peg <- new.parser(commonRules,action=TRUE) +
    c("HEADER   <- 'Header Info' EOL" , "{}"  ) + # Rule to match literal 'Header Info' and a \n, then discard
    c("TYPE     <- 'text' EOL"        , "{-}" ) + # Rule to match literal 'text', store paste and store as $TYPE
    c("DATE     <- (!EOL .)* EOL"     , "{-}" ) + # Rule to match any character leading up to a new line. Could improve to look for a date format
    c("EOS      <- '@' EOL"           , "{}"  ) + # Rule to match end of section, then discard
    c("BODY     <- (!EOS .)*"         , "{-}" ) + # Rule to match body of text, including newlines
    c("SECTION  <- DATE TYPE BODY EOS"        ) + # Combining rules to match each section
    c("DOCUMENT <- HEADER SECTION*"           )   # Combining more rules to match the endire document

res <- peg[["DOCUMENT"]](input))

final <- matrix( value(res), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE ) %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    setnames( names(value(res))[1:3])

final
```

Produces:

```
         DATE TYPE                       BODY
 1 2021-01-01 text multiple lines\nof\ntext\n
 2 2021-01-02 text      more\nlines of text\n
```

It might feel clunky if you don't know the syntax, but once you do, its a fire and forget solution. It'll run according to spec until the spec doesn't hold. You don't have to worry about fragile pretreatment and it is easy to adapt to changing formats in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know that this will work though, as the number of lines between each @ symbol is the same for a given file, but may be different for a different input file. I appreciate your input though

Comment: It doesn't care how many lines of text there is, it just parses down to the @ character

Comment: As you can see above in my sample input, one section has 3 lines of text, the other has 2 lines of text. It is not important, it just searches for the '@' that marks the end of each section.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to investigate it more

Comment: np, for this case I believe it's _probably_ overkill, it would depend on how flexible you need to be with the format, if it will change in the future etc. It's _declarative_ , meaning once you know the syntax well, it's easy to get things right with it. It likely won't be the fastest solution, but it offers other advantages like I said. It's available in multiple languages, but they're all more or less based on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar

Comment: Declarative in this case means, you're essentially saing, "My document contains a HEADER followed by one or more SECTIONs" (That's the last rule, defining DOCUMENT). Then further up you see the SECTION defined. It contains a DATE followed by a TYPE followed by a BODY followed by EOS (which is the @). Then Date, Type, Body and eos are defined further up etc. So you define independently what these things should be, and piece them together. Doesn't mean its easy though. But its powerful.

Comment: Actually this might be handy for another function I'm working on which needs to parse XML-like syntax, but is not XML, so the standard libraries don't work (I don't think).

Comment: It might help. There are peg grammars for xml out there you might adapt to your need.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the tidyverse way:

```
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)

max_columns <- 5

d <- {
  readr::read_file("file.txt") %>% 
  stringr::str_remove("^Header Info\n") %>% 
  tibble::enframe(name = NULL) %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep = "@\n")  %>% 
  separate("value", into = paste0("X", 1:max_columns) , sep = "\n") 
}
```

Using your example input in a file called file.txt, the d looks like:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  X1         X2    X3    X4    X5   
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 2021-01-01 text  ...   ""    NA   
2 2021-01-02 text  ...   ""    NA   
3 ...        NA    NA     NA   NA   
Warning message:
Expected 5 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 3 rows [1, 2, 3].
```

Note that the warning is simply to make sure you know you're getting NA's, this is inevitable if number of rows between @ varies

Answer (score 1):

I  am using the data similar to that provided by [Sirius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67064698/2884859) for demonstration. you can also do something like this to have variable number of columns in resulting data frame

```r
example <- "Header Info
2021-01-01
text
multiple lines
of
text
@
2021-01-02
text
more
lines of text
@"
library(tidyverse)

example %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames('dummy') %>%
  separate_rows(dummy, sep = '\\n') %>%
  filter(row_number() !=1) %>%
  group_by(rowid = rev(cumsum(rev(dummy == '@')))) %>%
  filter(dummy != '@') %>%
  mutate(name = paste0('X', row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid, names_from = name, values_from = dummy)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#> # Groups:   rowid [2]
#>   rowid X1         X2    X3             X4            X5   
#>   <int> <chr>      <chr> <chr>          <chr>         <chr>
#> 1     2 2021-01-01 text  multiple lines of            text 
#> 2     1 2021-01-02 text  more           lines of text <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>