# Fastest way to pad a dataframe with uneven columns

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

Similar to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060174/is-there-an-r-function-that-reads-text-files-with-n-as-a-column-delimiter) I'm trying to transform a vector into a dataframe in R. I use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67060741/1858667) where I turn it into a matrix and then data frame, but the issue is that some rows potentially have a different number of columns, which throws out my data frame. There can be an arbitrary number of values per row (i.e. not necessarily 3 columns as in the examples), so I check first to work out how many columns I need.

For example, given the example data below, I get a neat data frame.

```r
example <- c(
"col-a",
"col-b",
"col-c",
"col-a",
"col-b",
"col-c",
"col-a",
"col-b",
"col-c")

# Get the number of values between the repeating start == number of columns
ncols <- diff(grep("col-a", example))

data.frame(matrix(example, ncol = ncols[1], byrow = T))

#      X1    X2    X3
# 1 col-a col-b col-c
# 2 col-a col-b col-c
# 3 col-a col-b col-c
```

That's all well and good until I get a vector that has an extra value in one row (i.e. requires and extra column). For example:

```r
example <- c("col-a",
"col-b",
"col-c",
"col-a",
"col-b",
"col-c",
"WATCH OUT!",
"col-a",
"col-b",
"col-c")

# Get the number of values between the repeating start == number of columns
ncols <- diff(grep("col-a", example))

data.frame(matrix(example, ncol = ncols[1], byrow = T))

#           X1    X2    X3
# 1      col-a col-b col-c
# 2      col-a col-b col-c
# 3 WATCH OUT! col-a col-b
# 4      col-c col-a col-b
```

Whereas, what I really want is:

```
#           X1    X2    X3         X4
# 1      col-a col-b col-c         NA
# 2      col-a col-b col-c WATCH OUT!
# 3      col-a col-b col-c         NA
```

I could deal with this with a double for loop after checking that there is an uneven number of elements between first column elements, but that's not even going to be close to the best option surely.

The additional complication is that the "extra" column could potentially be anywhere, not necessarily the last column.
**Edit:** The column ordering is actually arbitrary, so there's no reason why the extra column has to be in the middle, it could be appended at the end. The is one option I considered, to pull it out and just append it after padding with `NA` afterwards. The text that should be in the same column are also delimited so it's clear where they belong. Have updated the example below.

Here is some more realistic example data and desired output:

```
example <- c("name:start",
"date:a",
"value:b",
"name:start",
"date:c",
"desc:WATCH OUT!",
"value:d",
"name:start",
"date:e",
"value:f")

# Desired output
     X1                         X2                               X3           X4
1 name:start     date:a                              NA   value:b  
2 name:start     date:c  desc:WATCH OUT!   value:d 
3 name:start     date:e                              NA   value:f
```

What would be the fastest way to process this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** the "blocks" that turn into rows are well defined, so the start and end of a block are clear and finding the size of a block isn't hard, hence my `diff(grep(...))` command earlier (could also use `dist()` for similar result). The WATCH OUT! Text can be arbitrary though, so it's not as simple as searching for WATCH OUT!.

Comment: Sorry but just to be clear, does it matter where WATCH OUT! is? For example the example data and output, does the watch out need to be in x3 or could it be in x4?

Comment: I think for any useful solution you need to better define the conditions of the problem – is the first column always constant? How is the bad element distinguishable from good elements? If it's as simple as finding "WATCH OUT!", you can just remove it, form the df, and place it in the appropriate row/new column based on the previous neighbors.

Comment: @otsu I was thinking about that after I posted the question, but want able to edit until now. The column ordering is arbitrary really, so the extra column could go on the end, and that would be fine.

Comment: @kwes I'll update to clarify a bit more what the problem is.  Unfortunately it's not as simple as just finding the text WATCH OUT! , because that text can be arbitrary, and anywhere within a "block". It's not so much that it's a "bad" element, as an extra one that then throws out the matrix formation. The blocks are well formed, in that they are clearly delineated, but some potentially have this extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if the output in this format, is useful

```r
example <- c("name:start",
             "date:a",
             "value:b",
             "name:start",
             "date:c",
             "desc:WATCH OUT!",
             "value:d",
             "name:start",
             "date:e",
             "value:f")
library(tidyverse)

example %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames('dummy') %>%
  separate(dummy, into=c("name", 'value'), sep = '\\:') %>%
  mutate(rowid = cumsum(name == first(name))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid, names_from = name, values_from = value)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   rowid name  date  value desc      
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
#> 1     1 start a     b     <NA>      
#> 2     2 start c     d     WATCH OUT!
#> 3     3 start e     f     <NA>
```

---

OR perhaps this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

example %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames('dummy') %>%
  separate(dummy, into=c("name", 'value'), sep = '\\:', remove = F) %>%
  mutate(rowid = cumsum(name == first(name))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid, names_from = name, values_from = dummy)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   rowid name       date   value   desc           
#>   <int> <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   <chr>          
#> 1     1 name:start date:a value:b <NA>           
#> 2     2 name:start date:c value:d desc:WATCH OUT!
#> 3     3 name:start date:e value:f <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

For your first example, you could do

````
``` r
example <- c("col-a",
             "col-b",
             "col-c",
             "col-a",
             "col-b",
             "col-c",
             "WATCH OUT!",
             "col-a",
             "col-b",
             "col-c")
library(tidyverse)

example %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames('dummy') %>%
  group_by(rowid = cumsum(dummy == first(dummy))) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0('X', row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid, names_from = name, values_from = dummy)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   rowid [3]
#>   rowid X1    X2    X3    X4        
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
#> 1     1 col-a col-b col-c <NA>      
#> 2     2 col-a col-b col-c WATCH OUT!
#> 3     3 col-a col-b col-c <NA>
````

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help! I've marked this as the accepted answer, because it worked, and gave me the inspiration to get to the solution I have used. The `separate` and `pivot_wider` steps were the keys!

Answer (score 1):

Is this useful?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rebus)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rebus'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stringr':
#> 
#>     regex
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     alpha

example <- c("name:start",
             "date:a",
             "value:b",
             "name:start",
             "date:c",
             "desc:WATCH OUT!",
             "value:d",
             "name:start",
             "date:e",
             "value:f")

example_dirty <- example #i will use it at the end of the script for replacing

custom_pattern <- rebus::or('name:.*', 'date:.', 'value:.') 


alien_text_index <- str_detect(example, pattern = custom_pattern) %>%
    as.character() 
replacement <- which(alien_text_index == 'FALSE') %>%
    `/`(., 3) %>% #in this case every three rows the repetition should start over.
    round() #round for getting an index to modify



example <- str_match(example , pattern = custom_pattern) %>% keep(~!is.na(.))

df <- c('name:.*', 'date:.', 'value:.') %>% 
    map(~example[str_detect(example, .x)])  %>% reduce(bind_cols) %>%
    mutate(..4 = '')
#> New names:
#> * NA -> ...1
#> * NA -> ...2
#> New names:
#> * NA -> ...3





for (i in length(replacement)) {
    df[replacement[i], 4] <- example_dirty[!as.logical(alien_text_index)][i]
}

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   ...1       ...2   ...3    ..4              
#>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   <chr>            
#> 1 name:start date:a value:b ""               
#> 2 name:start date:c value:d "desc:WATCH OUT!"
#> 3 name:start date:e value:f ""
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I appreciate your input, thank you for taking the time to propose a solution. Unfortunately I don't think this will work. Have a look at my updated now realistic example. The columns aren't necessarily delimited as 'col', but they do have a common delimiter, whereas the extra column data has a different delimiter. I also want to keep the extra data if possible, rather than discarding it.

Comment: @SamRogers i edited the answer to include the extra data and include the realistic example.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. I'm not sure it will completely solve my problem, but might give me something to start with.